# How to change second select list option, based on the selected option of a first select list?

Tags: jquery

hi i am new to jquery How to change second select list option, based on the selected option of a first select list 
for ex if i select weight i want to get ton i have multiple select list which has same option. and i tried as in snippet but i was not able get output.here i tried to get nearer selection list id and to change its value

```js
function myfun(selectobj) {
  $('#' + selectid.id).find('.nearSelcttxt').attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</header>
<label class="custom-control "> label1</label>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="labelBlack form-control" name="companyType" id="meas1" class="form-control">
               <option value="Weight"> Weight</option>
                <option value="Length">Length</option>
                <option value="Piece"> Piece</option>
            </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">

  <select class="labelBlack form-control" name="companyType" id="unt1" onchange="myfun(this)" required class="form-control nearSelcttxt">
                                 <option value="$/TON">$/TON</option>
                                  <option value="$/FT">$/FT</option>
                                  <option value="$/PIECE">$/PIECE</option>
                                </select>

</div>

<label class="custom-control "> label2</label>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="labelBlack form-control" name="companyType" id="meas2" class="form-control">
               <option value="Weight"> Weight</option>
                <option value="Length">Length</option>
                <option value="Piece"> Piece</option>
            </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="labelBlack form-control" name="companyType" id="unt2" onchange="myfun(this)" required class="form-control nearSelcttxt">
                                 <option value="$/TON">$/TON</option>
                                  <option value="$/FT">$/FT</option>
                                  <option value="$/PIECE">$/PIECE</option>
                                </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this example would hep you: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/65Q9L/

Comment: @Priya you want to reflect same value for all the select input if changed value of any select input?

Comment: @omi if i select first selection list as weight in second selection list i need to get ton in second list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to maintain `data-id` variable which will store the integer id as yop given for select id e.g. meas1,unt1 so for these select it will be `data-id="1"` same for all other select.

For change event either you can use `onchange` inside select or use global selector `.change()` event in script for that you need same to use same class name for all select e.g for measure select you can use `meas` and for unit use `unt` so no need to use `onchange` in each select.

**Note**: *You need to maintain the same order of measure & unit. Suppose weight is at 0 index in measure select then TON should be at 0 index.*

How this will work? - First we will find the `data-id` then we will get the selected option index. After that we will make the selector with `data-id` i.e `#meas+data-id` or `#unt+data-id`. Then we will that index option from another select with new id.

```js
$(".meas").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  $("#unt" + id).prop('selectedIndex', index);
});

$(".unt").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  $("#meas" + id).prop('selectedIndex', index);
});


function changeUnit(element) {
  var id = $(element).data('id');
  var index = $(element).prop('selectedIndex');
  $("#unt" + id).prop('selectedIndex', index);
}

function changeMeasure(element) {
  var id = $(element).data('id');
  var index = $(element).prop('selectedIndex');
  $("#meas" + id).prop('selectedIndex', index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</header>


<label class="custom-control "> label1</label>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select data-id="1" onchange="changeUnit(this)" class="labelBlack form-control meas" name="companyType" id="meas1" class="form-control">
        <option value="Weight"> Weight</option>
        <option value="Length">Length</option>
        <option value="Piece"> Piece</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">

  <select data-id="1" onchange="changeMeasure(this)" class="labelBlack form-control unt" name="companyType" id="unt1" required class="form-control nearSelcttxt">
        <option value="$/TON">$/TON</option>
        <option value="$/FT">$/FT</option>
        <option value="$/PIECE">$/PIECE</option>
    </select>

</div>

<label class="custom-control "> label2</label>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select data-id="2" class="labelBlack form-control meas" name="companyType" id="meas2" class="form-control">
        <option value="Weight"> Weight</option>
        <option value="Length">Length</option>
        <option value="Piece"> Piece</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select data-id="2" class="labelBlack form-control unt" name="companyType" id="unt2" required class="form-control nearSelcttxt">
        <option value="$/TON">$/TON</option>
        <option value="$/FT">$/FT</option>
        <option value="$/PIECE">$/PIECE</option>
    </select>

</div>
```